# Download Historic NSE Futures Data

Tags: python, stockquotes

I need to download NSE Futures data since 2012 for my strategy backtesting. I tried **NSEpy** and **jugaad-data** libraries but they are giving one day's data at a time.

I tried **Getbhavcopy** as well but the data is not accurate there.

Is there any other free source to download the same.

Thanks,
Mohit

Comment: bhavcopy can not be wrong. check your logic

Comment: I am talking about this bhavcopy. Here few dates are missing- https://www.getbhavcopy.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get as follows .....

```
from datetime import timedelta, date
from nsepy import get_history

def importdata(stock):
    stock_fut = get_history(symbol=stock,
           start=date.today() - timedelta(days = 14),           end=date.today(),
           futures=True,
           expiry_date=date(2022,11,24)) 
                              
    #print(stock_fut.columns)
    print(stock_fut[["Open","Close","Change in OI","Open Interest"]])
        
a = ["AARTIIND","ABB","ABBOTINDIA","ABCAPITAL","ABFRL","ACC","ADANIENT"]
    
for i in range(0,len(a)):
        print(a[i])
        importdata(a[i])
```

Comment: Thanks for submitting an answer.  Can you indent the code correctly please?

Comment: I have updated the script with correct indent.

Answer (score 0):

I've used NSEpy, this is basically scraping from the NSE website, better to use some API which actually has the right to provide the data. e.g: Samco, angel one APIs.

they are free as well.